MAC OS on AWS EC2- Need to use service account instead default ec2-user account and need it for hardening the OS
I have a requirement that MAC OS on AWS EC2, Need to use service account instead default ec2-user account while doing ssh like (ssh -i /path/to/your-key.pem ec2-user@your-instance-public-ip
), This is my first requirement and second requirement is need it for hardening the MAC OS -Sonoma which is running on the ec2.
My Project Overview :
I have asked to setup a new mac os sonoma in ec2 which is first time am going to do it. How can i do the hardening of the OS (As i checked and found CIS benchmark document but there are lot of information about the hardening, i want any standard process or procedure to do the hardening ) and also i don't want to use default ec2-user while ssh via vncviewer (like remote control ).
Did anyone do this in your day to day task/job. If yes, please guide me/refer me and I'm ready to connect with you to gain some knowledge about these requirement.
I have tried to copy the .pem file from ec2-user to newly created user account but unable to do the ssh.

This is not a programming question.

Any macOS instance you create in AWS is going to have whatever setup AWS has provided. Any changes you want to make after creation have to be done by you. So for example, removing the ability for the ec2-user to ssh into the machine, hardening, etc.
Depending on your level of sophistication, you can perform the changes in a few different ways:

Manually, by RDP'ing into the machine and using the macOS UI to perform the modifications you require.
Via code written in a provisioning tool such as Ansible.
Via an AMI creation tool such as Packer, possibly in conjunction with Ansible.

Options 1 and 2 must be repeated every time you create a new macOS instance. Option 3 can be run once and then using the resulting AMI to create your macOS instances.
BTW, macOS instances in AWS are insanely expensive. IIRC, after 2 or 3 months it's more cost-effective to buy your own Mac Mini.
